# COUNT one column per month (including null values) from the current month and the previous 6?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I have a table called observations, in it I have a field called observation and the date when the observation was created, I want to see how many observations have been made per month, during the current month and the previous 6 months, but I want that if there is no observation in some month it is counted as a 0.

I made this query

```
SELECT COUNT(observation) AS observ, MONTH(created_at) AS mont
FROM observations
WHERE created_at >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
GROUP BY mont;
```

in the table there are only 4 months with observations, the result of the query is this

[image]

but I would like it to give me a result like this

[image]

how could i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to join a Month table

> ```
> SELECT observ, MO.mo as mont
> FROM (SELECT COUNT(observation) AS observ, MONTH(created_at) AS mont
> FROM observations o 
> WHERE created_at >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
> GROUP BY mont) o RIGHT JOIN 
> ( SELECT 1 as mo UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6
> UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) MO
> ON o.mont = MO.mo
> ```
>
> ```
> observ | mont
> -----: | ---:
>   null |    1
>   null |    2
>   null |    3
>   null |    4
>   null |    5
>   null |    6
>   null |    7
>   null |    8
>      1 |    9
>   null |   10
>   null |   11
>   null |   12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eda1d983ec88c7c148228647856084fc)*

Comment: thanks for your answer<3 it works for me, i cant vote up you answer because i dont have 15 of reputation :(

Comment: no problem,please read for the next time https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question